# Git per character comparison. Any ways to filter output by comparison results?

Tags: git, split, diff

I have two large files (file1 and file2) and I'm comparing them on character level. As a result of comparison I have:

1. lines that equal in both files
2. lines that are present in file 1 but not in file 2
3. lines that are present in file 2 but absent in file 1
4. lines that are different among both files(with different chars highlighted)

Now I can get all this types of result altogether in one output and I can redirect it to single file via command line, or I can get split diff(in Notepad++ for instance)

But is there any way or utility or editor that will allow me to separate this comparison results? (e.g. have lines that are different among both files in one output and lines that are equal in both in another output(file))?

Comment: Are these files binaries?

Comment: Nope. It's csv files, but in context of this question they can be considered as plain text.